# pass docker cli args in dockerfile

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile, wiremock, wiremock-standalone

would like to know if there is way to pass below https-port argument in entrypoint script or in the dockerfile

**--https-port 443**

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8443:8443 wiremock/wiremock --https-port 8443 --verbose
```

here is the link to the dockerfile: https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock-docker/blob/main/Dockerfile

Link to EntryPoint script : https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock-docker/blob/main/docker-entrypoint.sh

Appreciated any help

**Note:** Our use case doesn't allow to use argument with special chars ( --https-port ) on docker run cli command, either it has to be in the dockefile or entrypoint script

Comment: Try `docker run -it --rm -p 8443:8443 wiremock/wiremock -- --https-port 8443 --verbose`

Comment: Anything you'd pass after the image name in a `docker run` command replaces the Dockerfile `CMD`.  If it's not a shell command you need to make sure you use the JSON-array form, lest Docker insert a `/bin/sh -c` wrapper you don't want.